# How to extract the data from a column when only multiple data exists for that value in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

SQL CODE:

```
select student.sex, class.date 
from ((student INNER JOIN student_course ON student.name=student_course.Student) 
    INNER JOIN class ON student_course.Course=class.Course);
```

Result:

```
sex  date   
m   25.2.19 
m   27.2.19 
m   27.2.19 
m   27.2.19 
m   25.2.19 
m   27.2.19 
m   25.2.19     
f   25.2.19 
f   27.2.19 
f   27.2.19 
f   25.2.19 
f   26.2.19
```

Now my target is to get the date where both male and female student appear. So
I modified the code to be:

```
SELECT o.date 
FROM (  select student.sex, class.date 
        from ((student INNER JOIN student_course ON student.name=student_course.Student) 
        INNER JOIN class ON student_course.Course=class.Course)) AS o 
WHERE o.sex='m' AND o.sex='f';
```

The result is NULL. But I want the result as:

```
date 
25.2.19
27.2.19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `JOIN` with aggregation, no any sub-query needed :

```
select c.date
from student s inner join
     student_course sc
     on s.name = sc.Student inner join
     class c
     on sc.Course = c.Course
where s.sex in ('F', 'M')
group by c.date;
```

This would display `date`S where it founds `male` or `female`, however your sample output suggests :

```
select c.date
from student s inner join
     student_course sc
     on s.name = sc.Student inner join
     class c
     on sc.Course = c.Course
where s.sex in ('F', 'M')
group by c.date
having count(distinct s.sex) = 2;
```

Comment: what is the purpose of s.student?

Comment: @Tathagata. . . That was typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dates with both male and female students, use aggregation:

```
select c.date
from student s INNER JOIN
     student_course sc
     ON s.name = sc.Student INNER JOIN
     class c
     ON sc.Course = c.Course
group by c.date
having min(s.sex) = 'F' and max(s.sex) = 'M';
```

If you have other genders, then you might want to filter on `where s.sex in ('F', 'M')` for the `having` logic to work.

Comment: what is the purpose of s.student?

Comment: @Tathagata . . . The typo has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer by @Yogesh Sharma
SQL CODE:

```
    select c.date
    from student s inner join
         student_course sc
         on s.name = sc.Student inner join
         class c
         on sc.Course = c.Course
    where s.sex in ('F', 'M')
    group by c.date
    having count(distinct s.sex) = 2;
```